# How do I put mutliple SlidingUpPanels on Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-sliding

I want to add multiple `SlidingUpPanel`s on my page, but I don't know how to do it. I did some research, but haven't identified a solution. If somebody can help me or give some another alternative I would be very satisfied. This is what I have so far, but the result is not what I am expecting.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sliding_up_panel/sliding_up_panel.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("SlidingUpPanelExample"),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text("This is the Widget behind the sliding panel"),
            ),
            SlidingUpPanel(
              panel: Center(
                child: Text("This is the sliding Widget"),
              ),
            ),
            SlidingUpPanel(
              panel: Center(
                child: Text("This is the sliding Widget 122"),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please put a video or something for the output you want so that we can help you?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I appreciate you adding your code, that is useful. Can you expand on what is not working? It would be useful for you to explain what you are _hoping_ this code will do, and what it is _actually_ doing.